# Angular 8: navigator.share() saying property `share()` does not exist

Tags: angular, typescript

We use version 8. PWA will have a function to share a pdf file, it already exists in the backend

```
Share(onload) {
  if (navigator.share) {
  navigator.share({
    title: 'web.dev',
    text: 'Check out web.dev.',
    url: 'https://web.dev/',
      })
    .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
    .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
    }
  }
```

...throws the error:

```
//     ERROR in src/.../my-orders.component.ts(118,19): error TS2339: Property 'share' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
    src/.../my-orders.component.ts(119,17): error TS2339: Property 'share' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.
```

Comment: How you defined navigator ? The type of navigator variable

Comment: Try to write this as a FAQ entry, not a conversation or message board post. The intent behind Stack Overflow is to be a database of answered questions, so anyone having the same problem in the future can find the answers you were given; "Hi, I'm new to Angular" doesn't really contribute to helping someone find the question (and thus its answers) -- so if anywhere that should be in the body, not the title.